# Brick wall with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, textures

I'm working on a program about a soliton going through a barrier and I'm trying to make the barrier look like a real one, so to say, to be made of bricks. The problem is that I couldn't found how to plot the 'brick' texture. I use `fill_between()` but if there's another option that admits bricks, I wouldn't have problem with using it.

My code is:

```
gs=GridSpec(8,1)  #7 rows and 1 column
state=self.fig.add_subplot(gs[2:,:])
light=self.fig.add_subplot(gs[0:2,:])
state.set_xlabel("Position ($x/ \\xi$)")
state.set_ylabel("Density $|\psi|^2 \\xi$")
state.plot(posit,phi2)
state.fill_between(posit,phi2,0,facecolor='0.80')
potential=state.twinx()
potential.plot(posit,pote,'g')
```

with all the arrays well defined and so. There's no problem with the code when running the program, but I would like to know how to draw the bricks if that's possible.

I attach an image of the actual situation, the barrier is empty for the moment waiting to be built with bricks, to make it more visual.

[image: Image of the plot]

Comment: If you can find a suitable image ... [This example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/demo_annotation_box.html#pylab-examples-example-code-demo-annotation-box-py) shws an image placed on a plot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be an example on how to place a brick wall into the image

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches

f = lambda x, x0, sig: np.exp(-(x-x0)**2/sig**2)

x = np.linspace(0,10, 301)
pulse = f(x, 2, 0.5)*2.8


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,4))

image = plt.imread("brick_texture104.png")
#http://p78i.imgup.net/brick_textadf0.png
im = ax.imshow(image, extent=[4,4+512./256,0,933./256] ) # image is 512 x 933, 
ax.set_aspect("equal")
ax.plot(x, pulse, color="r", alpha = 0.7, lw=4 )

wall_patch = matplotlib.patches.Rectangle((4.5,0),1,3, transform=ax.transData )
im.set_clip_path(wall_patch)

ax.set_ylim([0,4])
ax.set_xlim([0,10])
plt.show()
```

[image]